# Default gateway not available, "Ethernet" doesn't have valid IP configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

My last post was dismissed because lack of info and too broad of a question, so I've spent time getting info this time.

-Backstory

My connection to my internet Is perfectly fine, for hrs at a time.
Later becoming "connected, no access" this event will happen to anyone connected to the wifi or wired,

when connected via wired, tabs pop up and ask to sign in to your internet settings. when the internet gets troubleshooted, it says  "Ethernet" doesn't have valid IP configuration and Default gateway not available [Example of Wired TroubleShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahHhl.png)

when connected via wifi, it connects, no access. and pops up with a sign into the network, like free wifi at a store. and it asks for the internets info [(Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGAWq.png). but if troubleshooted, asks "are you trying to access a website" and "search for help"

-after

After the event starts, it takes about 15-20Min for the internet to fix its self. if i attempt to reboot my router it takes longer to fix itself. if i do sign into the internet through the promp, nothing happens and internets issue persists. if needed ill screenshot my /ipConfig when it happens again, ill gladly show anything else. just ask and ill try.

-Recaped/extra info

This happens to all devices attemping to connect to my internet

What my ipconfig looks like while internet is working fine [example of ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrqSf.png)

Wired connection is Windows 10

My wireless laptop is windows 8.1

My routers model is CGN3ACSMR by Hitron

Ask for more info if its needed please.

UPDATE: I the problem has happened again and i ended up ss the [IpConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSgpq.png) while the problem happened.

also Heres [ipconfig /all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZnz.png) For the one who asked this is when the internet is working

Comment: It would be most useful to see the ipconfig /all for both before and after the event.

Comment: Don’t add info in comments. [edit] your original post and add it.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson ill attempt to get it but ill post ipconfig /all for when the internet is fine rn

Comment: @Appleoddity my bad ill fix it

Comment: Are all these `ipconfig` outputs from the same computer? If so, why are you connecting wired and wirelessly at the same time. The difference in output between the two ipconfigs when working and not working is that you are connected to a wireless network that isn’t functioning properly when it’s not working.

Comment: @Appleoddity all of the ipconfigs working and not working, are from one computer which is wired.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to have both wireless and Ethernet adapters enabled and for both to have an IP address. The network adapters have a set numerical priority that will only use one connection at a time, so that probably isn't the problem here. However, your wireless is getting a 169.254.209.231 address, which probaly means it cannot find a DHCP server to get a proper address. When you have this issue, can you see what WiFi you're connecting to? Check out the network settings for the wireless adapter and make sure things are set to DHCP and no static information is set.

It's also worth noting that IPv6 can cause issues, so I typically disable the option from the Ethernet adapter. However, I don't believe that is the issue we're having now, but it's worth mentioning.

One thing you could do on your computer, at least, would be to disable the wireless so that your computer will only connect through the network cable. This would prevent your computer from trying to establish a wireless connection, which seems to be the problem at the moment.

Do you have multiple routers at your house or multiple DHCP servers running at your house? If so, make sure that only one is running so it doesn't fudge the network.

I don't know your network setup, but make sure that your devices are actually connecting to your Hitron WiFi by verifying the name of the Wifi that the devices are connecting to. Try and change the WiFi name on your Hitron and reconnect your devices to the new name on the off chance that devices might be trying to connect with saved network information.

You could also try and factory reset your Hitron, this would make sure that you're working with a clean slate and would help eliminate options while troubleshooting.